# Aspose - When I use page break, the shape disappears on a specific page

Tags: ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

I would like to have 4 shapes printed on each page.

If I run the generateWord() function, the shape is not printed only on the second page.

Why isn't the shape printed on the second page?

I am attaching the word file in question.

**generateWord()**

```
private fun generateWord(path: String) {
        val document = Document()
        val builder = DocumentBuilder(document)

        DocumentUtils.generateLine(builder)
        builder.insertBreak(BreakType.PAGE_BREAK)

        DocumentUtils.generateLine(builder)
        builder.insertBreak(BreakType.PAGE_BREAK)

        DocumentUtils.generateLine(builder)
        builder.insertBreak(BreakType.PAGE_BREAK)

        DocumentUtils.generateLine(builder)
        
        document.save(path)
}
```

**generateLine()**

```
fun generateLine(builder: DocumentBuilder) {
            builder.also {
                it.insertParagraph()
                val shape = Shape(builder.document, ShapeType.LINE).apply {
                    width = 452.0
                    top = 10.0
                }
                it.insertNode(shape)
            }
}
```

[question.docx](https://www.file.io/vOOu/download/ylx4kz3Uyq46)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code properly inserts a shape on each page of the generated document. See the screenshot of the generated document in MS Word.
[image]

Most likely the problem is caused by the consumer application, which is used to view the document.

Also if you need a shape on each page, maybe you can simply insert it into the primary header of the document.
https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/working-with-headers-and-footers/